# Convert to double from IMPORTXML in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting, google-sheets-formula

When I use the IMPORTXML function it retrieves me a **text** of a double with other format and I want to convert it to double.

I'm getting

> 1.258,00

But I want to convert it to

> 1,258.00

Otherwise google sheets doesn't recognize it as a double (I can't use the =VALUE() because of the format of the number). Thanks

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", ), ",", ".")*1
```

where A1 is your IMPORTXML formula

[image]

and format it as number:

[image]